# Error in app when i want to get data from preloaded database in android studio

Tags: android

The following are my different files
1.MainActivity.java

```
       package com.example.ganesha.myapplication;

  import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.SharedPreferences;
   import android.database.Cursor;
  import android.database.SQLException;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
  import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.Spinner;
  import android.widget.Toast;

 import java.io.IOException;
     import java.util.Calendar;
      import java.util.Locale;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText StudentName, StudentRollno;
//String selectedmess;
Context context = this;
Cursor c = null;
public static final String Mypref = "Mypreference";
public static final String Name = "StudentName";
public static final String Rollno = "StudentRollno";
public static final String Messname = "StudentSelectedMess";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b1;
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Mypref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
    StudentName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    StudentRollno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rollno);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.mess, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            HostelierDbHelper hostelierDbHelper = new HostelierDbHelper(MainActivity.this);
            try {

                hostelierDbHelper.create();

            } catch (IOException ioe) {

                throw new Error("Unable to create database");

            }

            try {

                hostelierDbHelper.open();

            } catch (SQLException sqle) {

                throw sqle;

            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            Calendar sCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            String dayLongName = sCalendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
            String m = "Thursday";
            int res = dayLongName.compareTo(m);
            if (res == 0) {

                c = hostelierDbHelper.query("Kailash",m,null, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,

                                        "Breakfast " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                                        "Lunch: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
                                        "Snacks:  " + c.getString(3) + "\n" +
                                        "Dinner:  " + c.getString(4),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

2.HostelierDbHelper
            package com.example.ganesha.myapplication;

```
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.database.SQLException;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
          import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.OutputStream;
        import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
        import java.util.Calendar;
        import java.util.Locale;



        public class HostelierDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static String DB_PATH = "";
private static String DB_NAME = "messmenus";
private static String TABLE_KAILASH = "kailash";
Cursor cursor;
//private static String TABLE_EMPLOYEE = "Employee";
//private static String TABLE_PHONE = "EmployeePhone";

private final Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase db;


public HostelierDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    } else {
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }
    this.context = context;
}

// Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
public void create() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        //do nothing - database already exist
    } else {
        // By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

// Check if the database exist to avoid re-copy the data
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database don't exist yet.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

// copy your assets db
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

//Open the database
public boolean open() {
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        db = null;
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (db != null)
        db.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

// Calendar sCalendar=Calendar.getInstance();
// String dayLongName = sCalendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
// String m="Monday";
//  int res=dayLongName.compareTo(m);
// if(res == 0){

public Cursor query(String table, String columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy) {
    return db.query("Kailash", new String[]{columns},null, null, null, null, null);

}
```

}
The following is the error logsheet

```
        07-21 20:46:10.602 8141-8189/com.example.ganesha.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
      07-21 20:46:10.637 8141-8189/com.example.ganesha.myapplication W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
         07-21 20:46:10.637 8141-8189/com.example.ganesha.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad154700, error=EGL_SUCCESS
        07-21 20:46:19.300 8141-8141/com.example.ganesha.myapplication E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: Kailash
           07-21 20:46:19.304 8141-8141/com.example.ganesha.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
          07-21 20:46:19.306 8141-8141/com.example.ganesha.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                         Process: com.example.ganesha.myapplication, PID: 8141
                                                                                       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Kailash (code   1): , while compiling: SELECT Thursday FROM Kailash
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
                                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
                                                                                           at com.example.ganesha.myapplication.HostelierDbHelper.query(HostelierDbHelper.java:137)
                                                                                       at com.example.ganesha.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:83)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Why does the error come when there is already a database and table[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Prd.png)

Comment: what error shows up?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest one without controlling the versions is,

```
private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + [Your Field definitions here] + " )";



@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
```

Your problem as in the stacktrace is that you are querying a db without creating it.

Comment: I did everything what you did but now I am not getting the final toast message of that breakfast,lunch dinner thing can you pls help